# You can find me in more than ten ways

Tags: riddle

> You can find me in more than ten ways

> My composition is associated with life itself.

> I'm the one who comes to the rescue if your body's damaged.

> I'm also older than the sun itself.

> **Who am I?**

Hints:

> Hint1 : My dust is well known and "pricy"!

> I can burn.

> **Answer:**

> Ice

> You can find me in more than ten ways

> Ice has over 15 phases.

> My composition is associated with life itself.

> Ice is solidified water. Water is associated with any sort of life as we know it.

> I'm the one who comes to the rescue if your body's damaged.

> If you hurt yourself, you put ice on the wound so it doesn't swell.

> I'm also older than the sun itself.

> There is evidence that earth had water (and ice!) even before the sun appeared.

> Hints

> Hint1 : My dust is well known and "pricy"!

> Diamond dust is also known as ice needles or ice crystals and forms due to air with slightly higher moisture from aloft mixing with colder, surface-based air. "Pricy" was because the literal meaning of the mineral "Diamond" is pricy.

> I can burn

> Ice can burn your skin.

Comment: I'll add another hint.

Comment: -1 because all the other answers were perfectly applicable... Also, as a side note, you should post the answer as... an answer rather than in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't know we had an answer option. But also, only one answer was applicable, not all of them.

Comment: Why did you accept hexomino's answer? So both ice and oxygen are valid answers according to you. And I think some of the other ones people have responded should also work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not totally sure, I think it might be

> Oxygen

You can find me in more than ten ways

> Oxygen has more than ten [isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_oxygen)

My composition is associated with life itself.

> Oxygen is one of the [six most important chemical elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHON) whose covalent combinations make up most biological molecules on Earth.

I'm the one who comes to the rescue if your body's damaged.

> Oxygen is used a lot in [medical treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_therapy)

I'm also older than the sun itself.

> It is one of the elements formed in the early stages of the universe so certainly much older than the sun.

Comment: It can be applicable. But that's not what I was looking for. I'll add a hint :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> a star

```
You can find me in more than ten ways
```

> There is around 10/12 types of star

```
My composition is associated with life itself.
```

> I don't know about that one but it could be Hydrogen?

```
I'm the one who comes to the rescue if your body's damaged.
```

> Star of Life is the symbol of medical services in the US.

```
I'm also older than the sun itself.
```

> Other stars used to exist before the sun.

hints

> stardust is a pricy material and a star is always burning.

Comment: Sorry mate that's not the answer.
@Deepthinker101 kinda guessed correctly one of his answers. Only one though.

Answer (score 1):

> It could be carbon, because 1) there are multiple compounds that contain carbon much more than ten 2) Carbon is found in DNA 3) Carbon is found in steel and steel equipments are used in surgical proceedures 4) Carbon is 14 billion years old 5) Diamond dust are made out of carbon and we all know how much they cost.

Comment: I can tell you that you are close. Carbon is very subjective. But one of the answers you gave is literally the name of one of its characteristics. If you look up the thing I'm referring to, you'll probably guess it correctly next time.

Answer (score 0):

> amino acids/protiens

More tha 10 types are present
Possibily older than sun
And they are very heloful in recovery

Comment: It can be applicable also, but its very subjective. I added another hint!